# how to change pointer into pointer-to-pointer?

Tags: c

I've rewritten my previous program and I want to change *dirty into **dirty. Could you give me some advise;
hERE'S my code:

```
void clean(char *dirty)
{
    int i = 0, j = 0;
    char *temp;

    temp = strdup(dirty);

    if(NULL == temp)
    {
        printf("strdup(), failed");
        return;
    }

    while(i < strlen(temp))
    {
        if(isalpha(temp[i]) || isspace(temp[i]) || temp[i] == '?'
            || temp[i] == '.' || temp[i] == '!' || temp[i] == ',')
        {
            dirty[j] = temp[i];
            j++;
        }
        i++;
    }
    dirty[j] = '\0';
    free(temp);
}
```

part of changed main(), i had some problems and together with my friend, we created this:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) 
{
    FILE* fp;
    char** tab;
    int i = 0;
    int lines = 0;
    int length = 10;

    if(argc != 2)
    {
        printf("Incorrent syntax! Use ./name_of_program input_file\n");
        return 1;
    }

    if(!(fp = fopen(argv[1],"r")))
    {
        printf("Could not open the file! Please try again!\n");
        return 2;
    }

    tab = (char**)malloc(length*(sizeof(char*)));
    if(!tab)
    {
        printf("Could not allocate memory!\n");
        free(tab);
        return 3;
    }

    while(!feof(fp))
    {
        tab[i] = getNumber(fp);

        if(i >= length) 
            {

                length += 10;
                tab = (char**)realloc(tab, sizeof(char*));
                if(tab == NULL)
                {
                    free(tab);
                    return 5;
                }
            }

        if(tab[i] == NULL)
        {
            printf("Incorrect character in the infile! Terminating\n");
            free(tab);
            return 4;
        ...
```

Comment: What do you want to accomplish with a `char **dirty` that you cannot do with `char *dirty`?

Comment: l've changed main() and now it requires **dirty. Just for practice.

Comment: what did you changed in main.You just modifying string just eliminating numbers and some other characters in function for this you just need single pointer. if you need to do the same for group of strings at a time you need double pointer or array of pointers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on what do you want to do, firs, note this in your main

```
tab = (char**)realloc(tab, sizeof(char*));
```

So you are reallocation your 10 pointer array into an array of pointers of size 1. Doesn't seem correct(realloc changes the memory allocated of the given pointer into the supplied size, if you supply more, like length* sizeof ... you'll increase the array size, of you don't you just loose all the data.

Now if you want to apply the "clean" function to an array of strings (char *), then you should include the current max size of the array. I would suggest you this, faster.

```
void clean_All(char ** strings, int size) 
{
     int i;

     if (strings == NULL)
         return;

     for(i = 0; i < size; i++) {
         if (strings[i] == NULL)
             return; 
         clean(strings[i]);
     }

     return;
}
```

Comment: thank you, i modified my program just to better understand pointer-to-pointer phenomena :)

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure what you mean. Something like this?

```
void clean(char** dirtyPointer)
{
    int i = 0, j = 0;
    char* dirty = *dirtyPointer;
    ...
```

Comment: That would have been my proposal as well. Strange question anyway.